# Does ml-engine provide a similar to Google Cloud Prediction blackbox?

Tags: google-cloud-ml

As Google Cloud Prediction API is deprecated (https://cloud.google.com/prediction/docs/end-of-life-faq), does ml-engine provide a similar black-box?

Answer (score 1):

Google Cloud ML Engine is managed TensorFlow and supports higher level APIs (see Datalab notebooks for [regression](https://github.com/googledatalab/notebooks/tree/master/samples/ML%20Toolbox/Regression/Census) and [image classification](https://github.com/googledatalab/notebooks/tree/master/samples/ML%20Toolbox/Image%20Classification/Flower) - runnable in [Datalab](https://cloud.google.com/datalab/docs/quickstarts)). Compared to Prediction API, there are some capability differences between the data types and some user experience delta that is being addressed in the near term.

Note that TensorFlow and ML Engine allow you a greater degree of freedom to select and tune the model & much larger scale than a blackbox - albeit with some added complexity at present. That too will be addressed soon.

Dinesh Kulkarni

Product Manager, Google Cloud ML & Datalab